# Rspec Testing : NoMethodError - undefined method 'id' for nil.Nilclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

When I am running rspec testing for a controller in Rails, I get the error `"NoMethodError : undefined method 'id' for nil.Nilclass"` at the second line.

params[:tag_id] is passed down from the front end, so I can't initialize that. 
How would I correct this error?

```
     #enables the id to be a name rather than just a number
    if (params[:tag_id].class) == String && (params[:tag_id]!= "alltags")
       tag_id = Tag.find_by(name: params[:tag_id]).id
    elsif params[:tag_id] == "alltags"
       tag_id = "alltags"
    else
       tag_id = params[:tag_id]
    end
```

Adding rspec test case

```
context "POST search_time_range" do
    it 'returns all data within a certain time range and where the tag_id matches' do
        params = {
            "range_start" => "2016-01-01",
            "range_end" => "2016-01-01",
            "tag_id" => "122"
        }

        post :search_time_range, params
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)

    end
```

Comment: `Tag.find_by(name: params[:tag_id])` isn't finding a `Tag` record. Are you sure you don't want `Tag.find(params[:tag_id])`?

Comment: Yes, All I want is to get the id if the value passed from front end is a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have a bug in:

```
Tag.find_by(name: params[:tag_id]).id
```

Which should be:

```
Tag.find_by(id: params[:tag_id]).id
```

Or:

```
Tag.find(params[:tag_id]).id
```

> `params[:tag_id]` is passed down from the front end

You need to pass `tag_id` into params when you make request from your spec. Keep in mind that you need to double check, that in your rspec you also create a valid `Tag` record in your database, which you will refer in your passed `params`

**Update**

```
context "POST search_time_range" do
    it 'returns all data within a certain time range and where the tag_id matches' do
        tag = Tag.create(name: '122')
        params = {
            "range_start" => "2016-01-01",
            "range_end" => "2016-01-01",
            "tag_id" => tag.name
        }

        post :search_time_range, params
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
end
```

As a quick and valid solution. But better to store your test data either in some kind of fixtures or use factory_girl.

Comment: params[:tag_id] is the name if it is String. So will need to find it by name equivalent in database.

Comment: Then you shouldn't call it tag_id. Use some generic name. Can you provide you spec file code?

Comment: Added rspec testcase in the question.

Comment: Updated my answer